# RestTemplate handling inconsistent types List<Object> vs Object

Tags: java, json, spring, prestashop, resttemplate

I have a problem with using a RestTemplate while fetching an API which has inconsistent data types of responses.

I wonder if there is a way to make it work without changing the API itself (API is not mine so I can't really change it)

I have a situation when i fetch a list of objects and when it returns not empty it's in format like this:

```
{
    "orders": [
        {
        ...
        }
     ]
}
```

But when i call this api with limit parameter or something else which returns 0 results then the format of response looks like that

```
[]
```

I have an object for serialization/deserialization and in it a list of orders so it works when i got more than 0 results. I don't know if there is a solution already on stack (i didn't found one yet).

Any ideas how to handle this sort of problem?

btw. I already created an issue on github for that API but untill it will be fixed I would like to get it working somehow (any hacks appreciated :) )

Edit:
Http status code is always 200

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this by using customized [objectmapper](https://dzone.com/articles/configuring-a-custom-objectmapper-for-spring-restt)

```
public ObjectMapper createObjectMapper() {
    ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    objectMapper.enable(DeserializationFeature.ACCEPT_SINGLE_VALUE_AS_ARRAY, true);
    return objectMapper;
}
```

To make the custom ObjectMapper available to MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter, simply create a new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter and pass in the ObjectMapper instance.

```
private MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter createMappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter() {
     MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter converter = new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter();
     converter.setObjectMapper(createObjectMapper());
     return converter;
}
```

Then, you can create a RestTemplate and add your custom MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter to its list of message converters.

```
@Bean
public RestTemplate createRestTemplate() {
     RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
     restTemplate.getMessageConverters().add(0, 
     createMappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter());
}
```

And then now use this `restTemplate` to read single object as `List`

```
List<Model> models = restTemplate.exchange(uri,POST,entity,
             new ParameterizedTypeReference<List<Model>>>(){});
```

Comment: Will it broke every other calls to API? What I mean is if now I need to change everywhere  from Model to List<Model> or it will choose the proper one?

Comment: No it will not break any existing functionality and you don't need to change anything, so if you intension is to parse single object as well into list they it will do, or if you want single object then just specify model @Szprota21

Comment: thanks, it seems like the best answer because it will be scalable for any similar errors in that API :)

Answer (score 0):

That sounds like a server-side problem rather than a client that reads the info. Try to invoke the same rest API with some browser-based REST client such as Advanced Rest Client (ARC) in chrome or any other client. See if you get the same structure of results for empty and non-empty list. If they are the same as you described above, than it is a server API problem and not your client's problem. So, if that's the case you have to check if your response is `[]` and convert it manually to `{ "orders":[]}`. If it is not the case, then look into your client or, maybe, use a different HTTP client

Comment: yea, it doesn't matter which client i use. I was just hoping that there is some solution which will prevent me from checking string for []. I already posted a issue on github but i guess that it won't be fixed soon :/

Comment: Well, if the server, gives you a wrong answer, you can not blame the client for reading it correctly...

Comment: That's true but I still need to make it work for the customer :)